# Failed to start mongodb with brew services - Abort trap: 6

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I just did a fresh install of mongodb using `brew install mongodb`. Running it with no config file `mongod` runs fine. But if I specify the default config file it errors.

```
$ mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
Abort trap: 6
```

brew services doesn't work either

```
$ brew services restart mongodb
Stopping `mongodb`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb)
==> Successfully started `mongodb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb)
$ brew services list
mongodb started ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

However the `started` is in yellow. I do have other services running and the `started` is green

**Files**

Both are the defaults generated by brew:

`/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

`~Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mongodb</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod</string>
    <string>--config</string>
    <string>/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <false/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/output.log</string>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/output.log</string>
  <key>HardResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>4096</integer>
  </dict>
  <key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>4096</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Log File:

```
[main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=25338 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=StarkTower
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.7
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: cf38c1b8a0a8dca4a11737581beafef4fe120bcd
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" } }
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /usr/local/var/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-08-17T22:09:28.961-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7680M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-08-17T22:09:29.720-0400 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1503022169:720091][25338:0x7fffd39fa3c0], file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: unable to read root page from file:sizeStorer.wt: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2017-08-17T22:09:29.721-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_size_storer.cpp 69
2017-08-17T22:09:29.721-0400 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after invariant() failure


2017-08-17T22:09:29.738-0400 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Abort trap: 6).
```

Comment: So what does `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` say? It is a log file and if there is any problem with startup there should be a detailed message there telling you why.

Comment: Also you either pasted your `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` contents incorrectly or there are formatting errors in the YAML. `storage:` should be it's own top level key, but appears "indented" as you have posted it.

Comment: @NeilLunn pasted it wrong fixed the YAML

Comment: The log file?? You need to actually look at the log file as it will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: It's suggesting that data is corrupted. Is this a fresh install? Or are you expecting some data to already be there? The latter would suggest that you actually had a crash not mentioned in your question. If it's meant to be a fresh install then simply remove the data files from the directory and start up again.

Comment: Made that deduction as well. I had already run `mongodb --repair` with no success. But after specifying the db file and engine `mongod --repair --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --storageEngine wiredTiger` it worked. Thanks for your help @NeilLunn

Comment: Excellent support from @NeilLunn. With MongoDB on mongodb-community@4.2 using mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf I found that I used :mongod --repair --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --storageEngine wiredTiger".